# Jquery no funciona en laravel 5.3

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Tengo un problema con mi Jquery en laravel, lo tengo puesto en la carpeta Public y lo tengo puesto con el siguiente codigo en mi Template principal de la siguiente forma:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.1.1.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
```

En la consola de artisan me dice el siguiente el error cuando le doy click a mis dropdowns y cuando pongo inputs tipo date y cosas asi que requieren el Jquery: Invalid Request EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> en Chrome revisa si no te tira un error 404 porque no solo debe estar en public sino también en la carpeta JS...adicionalmente Laravel no puede "saber" que JQuery tiene errores, o si no está "bien colocado", me explico, básicamente tu línea de carga donde llamas JQuery Laravel solo crea una ruta a ese archivo, la imprime y se acabó, el demás trabajo al ser ya parte del "front end" se lo deja al navegador quien debe interpretar y cargar los archivos estáticos necesarios.

**Primera edición:**
Comando que podría ser auxiliar:

```
php artisan clear-compiled && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan optimize
```

Comment: De hecho esta en public, y las carpetas tienen los permisos, por que si no lo tuvieron tampoco el bootstrap lo tomaria en cuenta,

Comment: Como dije, eso se me haría ridículo pero una vez nos pasó con una imagen que por alguna razón perdió permisos de escritura, quise comentarlo por si llegaba a pasar,  prueba este comando `php artisan clear-compiled && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan optimize`

Comment: ya lo realize y nada, me sigue tirando el error Invalid request EOF:

Comment: [Thu Dec 29 10:58:19 2016] 127.0.0.1:33230 [200]: /js/jquery-2.1.4.js
[Thu Dec 29 10:58:19 2016] 127.0.0.1:33228 [200]: /js/bootstrap.js
[Thu Dec 29 10:58:25 2016] 127.0.0.1:33234 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Thu Dec 29 10:58:25 2016] 127.0.0.1:33236 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Comment: El error entonces no está en esas librerías, está en alguna parte del código, en si, recordando, el lado del cliente es todo aquello contenido estático que es controlado a través del navegador, código JavaScript, código CSS, HTML, imágenes... JavaScript (a excepción de los relacionados a backend) no puede decirle a Laravel "tengo errores" porque Laravel no interactua con JavaScript directamente, no puedes hacer `<?php $variable = $("#id").val(); ?>` por así ponerlo, ahora bien, este error, si no mal recuerdo era de Laravel 4, en algunas situaciones, ¿qué versión de PHP y Laravel corres?

Comment: esta corriendo en version 5.3, lei que pudiese ser la version del jquery pero igual tengo la version reciente que es 3.1.1 los dos tengo en la carpeta pero solo llamo a uno.

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas cargar ambas librerías desde una CDN?, el problema podría ser a lo que estoy leyendo no por jQuery si no por un mal "empate" con {{  asset('') }}...si ahí está el error prueba cargando desde una CDN y asset() ya no interviene ni tampoco en si Laravel. Lo único que sería es que uses la versión que gustes.

Comment: con CDN si funciona, el pedo es que tengo mis propios cambios en el bootstrap que manejo. cuando dejo mi bootstrap con la CDN de jquery no funciona !, si cargo los dos CDN si funciona.

Comment: Ok entonces: 2 CDNS = Funciona. CDN Jquery + Bootstrap interno = No funciona. JQuery interno + CDN Bootstrap = No es posible. Si tomamos esto, entonces en si, sigo pensando que no es como tal error de Laravel, ¿podrías intentar cargar ambas librerías con la ruta relativa sin usar la función asset?. `URL::route()` y tratar de hacer que cargue de esta forma...a ver qué error tira.

Comment: <script src="{{URL::route('js/jquery-2.1.4.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::route('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>

Comment: me dice: que no he defino el jquery

Comment: Disculpa, mi error, es: `<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>` no "route" sino "asset". A ver si así funciona. En otro caso prueba con "URL::to()" (checa la documentación ya que este agrega si no mal recuerdo index.php al path)

Comment: También recuerda que tienes las alternativas de la clase HTML : `{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.js') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }} `

Comment: <script src="{{URL::asset('js/jquery-2.1.4.js')}}"></script>
 <script src="{{URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>

Comment: aun asi no funciona jejejee :V

Comment: Entonces no estoy muy seguro ya que hay muchas variantes, te tocará investigar ya que aquí lo único que se me ocurre es que o tus vistas tienen un error de cierre y las cargas mal, o tu código Laravel está dañado previo a estas línea, tu instalación de PHP está incorrecta/dañada, etc. Realmente saber esto un tanto al aire es muy improbable que se te resuelva el conflicto.

Comment: `<script src="{{URL::asset('js/jquery-3.1.1.js')}}"></script>
 <script src="{{URL::asset('plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script> `, tuve un error estaba llamando al bootstrap.js de public y no de mi frame !, gracias por la ayuda :D, ese comando me salve para algo por que siempre se fresea el laravel con tanta prueba

Comment: Hahaha ok...pues que bueno que ya se resolvió, eso se te hubiera solucionado relativamente revisando la consola de chrome (a menos que tuvieras otro bootstrap)... Ahí le encargo que me marque como respuesta aceptada(? Haha ...suerte.